# Taking care of the complete URL for the router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm experimenting angularjs on my own website. My problem is that I want the same content on the URL http://website.com/foo/bar with and without JS.

- When I come on "/" and JS, I can move to "/foo/bar", no problem.
- If I refresh without JS, no problem.
- If I refresh with JS, angular is not able to generate the wanted content.

I think the problem is from `$location` which doesn't take care of the complete url as suggest [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/116).

How force angular to take care of the complete URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use the title field to "tag" your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to specifie the base with a specific tag in your HTML:

```
<base href="/" /> <!-- or any other base -->
```